# Howto verify if Storage Spaces uses Journal disks

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

I try to add three SSDs as journal disks to an existing Storage Space (with powershell commands Add-PhysicalDisk and Set-PhysicalDisk -usage journal).

However strangely this increased the size of the storage pool (get-storagepool | select size).

How can I detect whether the added disks are really used for Parity Journal and Write Back Cache? Or is it not possible to add this to an already existing storage space?

Answer (score 4):

Get-PhysicalDisk PowerShell cmdlet is your best friend. Loop over all disks in your system checking "-Usage" parameter. For journal disks it will be "Journal" (surprise!). If there are no "Journal" disks detected your pool isn't using journalling disks.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-physicaldisk?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 1):

I use this to verify Journal on my parity space for my F: drive (serialnumber / uniqueid omitted here, only 26 GB at the end of the the SSD are used for the Journal, the rest is a normal drive):

```
PS C:\> Get-StoragePool -FriendlyName Pool-F | Get-PhysicalDisk | ft FriendlyName,MediaType,HealthStatus,canpool,CannotPoolReason,size,uniqueid,SerialNumber,Usage
FriendlyName            MediaType HealthStatus canpool CannotPoolReason          size Usage
------------            --------- ------------ ------- ----------------          ---- -----
WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0    HDD       Healthy        False In a Pool        3000592982016 Auto-Select
WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0    HDD       Healthy        False In a Pool        3000592982016 Auto-Select
Samsung SSD 860 EVO 4TB SSD       Healthy        False In a Pool        4000787030016 Journal
ST33000651AS            HDD       Healthy        False In a Pool        3000592982016 Auto-Select
```